# PHP 7.1 Register_Globals

Tags: php, centos

Another odd question here. I've recently been apart of a huge upgrade from PHP 5 to Php 7.1 along with CentOS upgrade as well.

We have a lot of pages (almost all of them in fact) that used the register global shortcut in the code.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $data['password'];
$_SESSION['accountid'] = $data['accountid'];
$_SESSION['role'] = $data['role'];

$getCompany = mysqli_query($mysqli_con,"SELECT * FROM companies WHERE companyid='$data[accountid]'");
$dataCompany = mysqli_fetch_array($getCompany);

$delinquent = $dataCompany['delinquency'];

// Here I fixed it
$item = $_GET['item'];
// But generally variables are just referenced by $whatevergetparameter
if($delinquent == 0){
switch($item)
{
    // Settings
    case "cannedresponses":
        include("/master/inc/settings/list-cannedresponse.inc");
    break;

    case "serviceboard":
        include("/master/inc/settings/list-serviceboard.inc");
    break;

    case "pending-direct":
        include("/master/inc/direct/pending.inc");
    break;
```

Naturally this has caused a lot of problems. Especially since it is everywhere.

There are plans for a re-write in the works but in the meantime I was wondering if anyone knows a workaround to imitate or "enable" register_globals so we can get functionality up and running.

I've looked and tried the solutions:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php
But unfortunately they don't work which isn't surprising since they were written 3 years ago.

My Google-Fu isn't helping me here either :/

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can turn register globals back on. Your only option with PHP 7.1 is to continue rewriting. Quite frankly, I wouldn't run any application in production that was depending on register globals.

Comment: I can't see any register globals issue within your code ?

Comment: @mkaatman The issue here I went ahead and fixed it by adding the GET. I added that line to get it to work here. But alot of the code just references it by $item or $service (since with register_globals it would just assume that was the get variable).

Comment: @hassan If I had any say in it we'd be doing a re-write now but Management is king...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a temporary solution in the meantime.

We utilize an include often in almost all of our pages that includes functions, db connections, etc.

I begun listing the GET / POST variables we use everywhere there.

```
if(isset($_GET["outsource"]))
        $outsource = $_GET["outsource"];
else
    $outsource = "";

// Our Selector for a lot of our Select case Usage
if(isset($_GET["item"]))
        $item = $_GET["item"];
else
    $item = "";

// Order Stuff
if(isset($_GET["orderby"]))
        $orderby = $_GET["orderby"];
else
    $orderby = "";
```

It's not the cleanest solution, and it's not the best solution but it "works".

Comment: `foreach (['outsource', 'item', 'orderby'] as $var) { $$var = $_GET[$var] ?? ''; }`

Comment: That is a lot cleaner! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* just create your own globals from GPC:

```
foreach (['_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE'] as $source) {
    foreach ($$source as $key => $value) {
        $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: Don't ever actually do this.

Comment: Yeah I've seen this as a solution but I'm trying to make it just a little bit more secure than that :)

Comment: You can't have register_globals *and* security. Pick one.